# Make Django query result as a linked list

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model which has 4 fields including id, from_id, name, project_id. It presents a transaction record about this project. For example:

```
id  from_id   name   project_id
 1   null       A         1
 2     1        B         1
 3   null       B         2
 4     2        C         1
 5     3        A         2
```

So how can I get a linked list likes A->B->C for project 1 or B->A for project 2?
(A->B->C and C->B->A are both great, I just want to get the transaction by query)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
select project_id,string_agg(name,',' order by from_id) from table group by project_id.
```

This will give you a list of nodes for each project_id.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield).